# Where are Guest OS's stored on vSphere disk?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

My Vsphere machine failed.  I took out 2 hard drives and want to copy over my VM's.  When I mount either of them, I see Hypervisor0-3 and a 4.3 GB Filesystem (in Ubuntu).

Anybody have any ideas on where my VM's are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files system is [VMFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware_VMFS) and there is an open source implementation [here](http://code.google.com/p/vmfs/).

Although, I believe it only allows for read-only access to the VMFS.

There is a nice article on [ZDnet](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/perlow/vmfs-3-how-do-i-despise-thee/11084) on how the writer despise VMFS...it does cover the issue you are facing right now.

> The only way you can move data in and out of their VMFS-3 file system
>   is using their provided proprietary tools, in this case the VMWare
>   vCenter Client which is used to remotely administrate an ESX box from
>   a Windows workstation or server, or their Linux command line console
>   which is only available on the full blown VI3/ESX 3.5 or vSphere 4.0
>   product, not the embedded ESXi version which is becoming increasingly
>   popular with environments using server blades.